# How do you reduce the size of a windows 7 offline image after you removed the old 3rd party drivers via DISM?

Tags: windows-7, deployment, dism, imaging

As the title says I had a Windows offline image that needed a driver package put on it from a CAB file I extracted the CAB file and used DISM to install all the drivers from it recursively. Some time later it has been determined those drivers won't see use anymore. After removing all those drivers the image is still the same size. It was 378MB before adding the drivers, and 1GB after. After removing the drivers using DISM it is still 1GB. So with that said something is lingering.

How can I accomplish the task of reducing the size of the image back to its original size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DISM included with the Windows ADK for Windows 7 lacks this feature, it is only available in Windows ADK for Windows 8.1 and later.

So for the DISM /Export-Image command in the accepted answer to work, you must use a more recent DISM. It won't work with the one included in the Windows 7 ADK.

The accepted answer also does not mention the different compression options. So if /Compress:maximum (or short /Compress:max) does not work, try /Compress:fast or /Compress:none.

/Compress:recovery offers the best compression rate but should only be used when creating ESD files. It also requires lots of CPU power and will keep all your CPU cores 100% busy for some time. Unfortunately, you cannot simply replace the install.wim with an install.esd file on Windows 7 ISO images. This will result in an non-bootable disc. As is with the /Compress option, this only works for Windows 8.1 or higher images.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DISM /Export-Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh825258.aspx) to create a new WIM and this reduces the size:

> **/Export-Image:**  Exports a copy of the specified image to another file. The source and destination files must use the same compression
>   type. You can also optimize an image by exporting to a new image file.
>   When you modify an image, DISM stores additional resource files that
>   increase the overall size of the image. **Exporting the image will
>   remove unnecessary resource files.**

```
Dism /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:install.wim /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:install2.wim /Compress:maximum
```